# How to install Playmemories home Software?

Tags: software-installation, wine, vaio, sony

I use Sony Vaio laptop. And I would like to install playmemories home, which is a software developed and released by Sony which is not available for Linux I believe. But for a testing I want to install it to import the files I have in my Camera. So I want to install the software in ubuntu.Can I do it with wine or is there a version for Linux as separate?

Answer (score 6):

I ran it on Linux using a Windows VM on VirtualBox for about a year.  It was a pain to get all working and having a whole VM running was a huge resource hog.

I just started a mini github project to get picture/video transferring over WiFi working on Linux without Playmemories.  I have it working for my A5000 and I'd be interested if other are able to make it work.  Here is the link:
https://github.com/falk0069/sony-pm-alt